# Error al compilar en LibGDX "finished with non-zero exit value 1"

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

al compilar mi juego en Android Studio con LibGDX me salta este error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Lo curioso es que la aplicación no se lanza al teléfono cuando lo quiero ejecutar, pero en el escritorio sí lo hace.

Este es mi archivo: `build.gradle`

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    compileSdkVersion 23
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.globapps.supermarioclon"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}


// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")        
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.globapps.supermarioclon/com.globapps.supermarioclon.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Resultados de la consola:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:android:generateDebugSources, :android:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:android:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android:checkDebugManifest
:android:prepareDebugDependencies
:android:compileDebugAidl
:android:compileDebugRenderscript
:android:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:android:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:android:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:android:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:android:generateDebugResources
:android:mergeDebugResources
:android:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:android:processDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:Total time: 5.212 secs
Information:See complete output in console
```

¿Alguien conoce alguna solución?

Comment: puede poner la traza completa, y si es posible su gradle. Saludos

Comment: He puesto el gradle en una respuesta. A que se refiere con la traza? La solución de su segundo comentario no ha funcionado.

Comment: @DDenche realiza primeramente lo que comenta AngelAngel > Build -> Clean Project | Build -> Rebuild Project  con eso me soluciona el problema a mí.

Comment: con la traza me referia, al uso de ./gradlew assembleDebug --info por ejemplo te muestra algo asi -> https://www.google.es/search?q=./gradlew+assembleDebug+--info&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp6L3_5JXLAhVDVRoKHSc4A1gQ_AUIDSgA&biw=1024&bih=657#imgrc=IuqZtYXmsG-P1M%3A

Comment: recientemente a añadido algun drawable nuevo o algo relacionado con las imagenes

Comment: por mirar esto no pierde nada, cierre el AS y elimine el proceso de Java igual lo tiene por las nubes

Comment: En drawable solo me aparecen los iconos de ic_launcher. Cuando cierro Android Studio en el administrador de tares no aparece Java :/

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente trata un `clean` y `build` de tu proyecto, regularmente eso me funciona a mi:

<kbd>Build</kbd>  -> <kbd>Clean Project</kbd>

después realiza:

<kbd>Build</kbd>  -> <kbd>Rebuild Project</kbd>

si eso no es suficiente, te recomiendo usar la más reciente versión de Android Build Tools:

dentro de tu `build.gradle`

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 23
    ...
    ...
    ....
```

- Realiza el cambio en tu `build.gradle` ya que indicas tener `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`
  Sin embargo en el mensaje de error indica la última versión: `build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe`

Comment: He hecho todo eso, también he cambiado la versión de Android Build Tools, y sigue dando error.

Comment: En tu build.gradle tienes definido  buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"  si revisas el mensaje de error indica la última versión build-tools\23.0.2\ cambia a como lo tengo en mi respuesta y comentame que resultado tienes. :)

Comment: Sigue apareciendo el mismo con la última versión.

Comment: Asegura volver a hacer un Clean & Rebuild.

Comment: Sigue dando el error. Quizá tenga que ver con alguna actualización que haya hecho?